# Font style gets changed issue in Xcode 11 Beta

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode11

1. Create a new or open existing project in `Xcode 11 Beta`.
2. Create `UILabel` with `Plain` text and keep the System font with Regular style.

[image]

3. Change text type to `Attributed` String and check font style, seems it changes with different font style and doesn't keep the same.

[image]

**PS: In `Xcode 10` work fine.**

Comment: Do you solve the issue?

Comment: Download & install SF Pro font then simply set from list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per Apple's official document https://developer.apple.com/fonts/
>
> **SF Pro:**
>
> This sans-serif typeface is the system font for iOS, macOS, and tvOS,
>   and includes a rounded variant. It provides a consistent, legible, and
>   friendly typographic voice.
>
> **SF Compact:**
>
> This sans-serif typeface is the system font for watchOS,
>   and includes a rounded variant. It suits a wide range of content and
>   is easily legible in a variety of contexts.

So we need to download and install **SF Pro** font and set `UILabel` attributed string font style with `SF Pro Text Regular 18.0` to keep the same font style like Plain text have.

Hope this will help you!

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your answer. Does it mean that now we have to tell the system to use "SF Pro" with some font size instead of using UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1), for example?

Comment: Actually, yes! In my particular case the problem wasn't triggered by XCode, it was a bug with Swift Rich String library so I had to correct just one line in its source and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that starting from iOS13 and XCode 11 Apple changed the system font for attributed string to this new, serif, Times-like font :(

([See also here](https://openradar.appspot.com/6153065))

I'm not sure if this was intentional or this is a bug in iOS. I do an ugly workaround to handle this problem:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUI-Regular" size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out what was happening.